# Pattern match in file

Tags: python, full-text-search

I am trying to find multiple matches in a file. I use the following code:

```
f = open('/home/evi.nastou/Documenten/filename')
text = f.read()
#print text
urls = re.findall(r"_8o _8r lfloat\" href=\"(.+?)\" onclick=", text)
for url in urls:
    print url.replace('\\','')
```

but it doesn't return any results.

On the other hand, when i pass the whole text in a variable it does find the patterns. 
Can someone please help me?

p.s. Part of the text in the file:

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"domops":[["replace","#detailedsearch_more_pager",f‌​alse,{"__html":"\u003Cdiv>\u003Cdiv class=\"mbm detailedsearch_result\">\u003Cdiv class=\"clearfix\">\u003Ca class=\"_8o _8r lfloat\" href=\"http://www.facebook.com/name\" onclick=\"if (event.button == 0) {
>       search_logged_ajax({"ab":"T_TA_RANKING_1","cururl&‌​quot;:"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\\

Comment: can you provide some parts of the file you are trying to read!

Comment: theAlse's comment +The with part you that is of interest to you.

Comment: @evi Post that in the question.

Comment: Are you searching through a file with html within? If so, why not use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: it is not html. i would say kind of json format, but not properly formatted as far as i can say. that's why i am using regular expressions

Comment: the text you have provided includes unsupported characters, try creating a variable in python with the text you have provided and you will see!

Comment: @theAlse Save it in a txt file(ASCII). Then load that file. NotePad is useful at times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be your regex.

Use this one:

```
r'href\s*=\s*(.+)\s+onclick\s*='
```

Code:

```
import re
text = open('test.txt').read() # contains your string

urls = re.findall(r'href\s*=\s*(.+?)\s+onclick\s*=', text)
for url in urls:
    print url.replace('\\','')
```

Output:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/name"
```

Explanation of my regex:

```
href    # match href
\s*     # match 0 or more spaces
=       # match =
\s*     # match 0 or more spaces
(.+?)   # match any character (non - greedy)
\s+     # match 1 or more spaces
onclick # match onclick
\s*     # match 0 or more spaces
=       # match =
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this! I thought that the regex was correct since it was working on a local variable. I played a bit with the expression you wrote since i want to extract only the urls that are in between _8o _8r lfloat\" and onclick. And it works!